# Use preprocess data in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm new in JSP. I did lots of preprocessing task when the first page is loaded. When user search I use that preprocess data and display the result in next page. After of that when user searches for the next time I use result.jsp which again preprocess the data. So, the every-time preprocessing task takes longer time. So, how can I avoid these preprocessing stuff.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Avoid the pre-processing by not pre-processing.

Comment: could you add some details about what preprocess data means? Usually if the search is performed against a database the data from the data base needs to be wrapped into java objects and then from the java objects displayed into a page. If this is the type of preprocessing you are referring to I don't think there are solutions to avoid it unless the data base is queried from the JSP, but this should definitely not happen

Comment: I have initialized many variables when page is loaded first time. Then this data is used when someone searches for the query like google search engine. Then in second-page user can search again if he/she wants. Then second time I have to do all the variable initialization and process the data again. This takes long time. I just want to use the data which is already initialized or processed.

Comment: The reusable variables once initialised could be stored on the http session, but if the variables are used for search criteria then they cannot be reused as most probably they don't match between two searches

Comment: some code fragments with the variables which you want to reuse would be really helpful

Comment: Use session and static variables. If you have common tasks for every request use filters.